# Are the historical differences in Tarantino's alternate history movies mentioned in any of his other movies?

Tags: reference, quentin-tarantino

Quentin Tarantino has three movies in his alternate history universe: *Django Unchained* (2012), *Inglourious Basterds* (2009), and *Once Upon a Time in Hollywood* (2019).

Are any of the historical changes in these movies mentioned in any of the other movies directly or with Easter eggs?

Please note I am not asking about connections between the movies, I am asking about mentions of the 'alternate' aspects of the movies i.e. Hitler's death in the movie theater.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In what Tarantino himself calls the "realer than real universe" the world operates a lot like the real one, where fictional characters can interact with real ones (such as Sharon Tate, Charles Manson, and Bruce Lee in *Once Upon A Time In Hollywood*, for example). Despite that, there seems to be no mention of the alternate historical events in any of the other movies.